# In SuiteScript, can you set the customform field using record.submitFields?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a partner record where I would like to change the form if the category field is set to a certain value. However, I can't use this with certain SuiteScript functions because changing the form wipes out any changes that were made to the record. I'm trying to work around this using an afterSubmit function that will use record.SubmitFields to change the form and then redirect.toRecord to reload the page with the change. However, it's not changing the form value. Is there a way to do this with record.submitFields? Am I doing something incorrectly?

```
            var currentRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
            var category = currentRecord.getValue('category');

            if(category == '3'){
                try{
                    record.submitFields({
                        type: record.Type.PARTNER,
                        id: currentRecord.id,
                        values: {
                            'customform': '105'
                        }
                    });
                    log.debug('success');
                } catch (e) {
                    log.error({title: 'error', details: e});
                }

            }

            redirect.toRecord({
                type: 'partner',
                id: currentRecord.id,
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Whenever you create a url for a record you can generally add a cf parameter that takes the form id. It's the same vaule you'd use if you were setting the field 'customform'. So just skip the submitFields part and do:

```
redirect.toRecord({
    type: 'partner',
    id: currentRecord.id,
    parameters:{
       cf:105
    }
});
```

You can also set the custom form using the submitFields call but that only works for some types of records.

If you need to do this in the beforeLoad here is a fragment in Typescript. The trick to avoid an infinite loop is to check to see if you already have the correct form:

```
export function beforeLoad(ctx){
    let rec : record.Record  = ctx.newRecord;
    let user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
    if(user.roleCenter =='EMPLOYEE'){
        if(rec.getValue({fieldId:'assigned'}) != user.id){
            throw new Error('You do not have access to this record');
            return;
        }
    }else{
        log.debug({
            title:'Access for '+ user.entityid, 
            details:user.roleCenter
        });
    }
    
    if(ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.EDIT){
        var approvalForm = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name:'custscript_kotn_approval_form'});
        let rec : record.Record  = ctx.newRecord;
        if( 3 == rec.getValue({fieldId:'custevent_kotn_approval_status'})){
            if(approvalForm != rec.getValue({fieldId:'customform'}) && approvalForm != ctx.request.parameters.cf){
                redirect.toRecord({
                    type: <string>rec.type,
                    id : ''+rec.id,
                    isEditMode:true,
                    parameters :{
                        cf:approvalForm
                    }

                });
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this beforeLoad? I'd like to find a way to load the correct form when the user first pulls up the record. When I put my code there, the page loaded endlessly and then crashed.

Comment: It got stuck in an infinite loop when putting it beforeLoad. And obviously since the form value is not being saved to the database, the old form will always pull up unless you re-submit the record.

Comment: Have you tried moving it to a pageInit client side script instead of a before load?

Comment: The onBeforeLoad context also has access to the request parameters. I've updated the sample to show how to check that as well.

Comment: @bknights Will this only work if the record is in edit mode? Is there a way to do it on record view?

Comment: Yes of course. See how the UserEventType test is for Edit mode and the redirect has an isEditMode parameter. Just make the appropriate changes for View mode.